# How to change me in contacts

Tags: contacts, ios

In my contacts, there is a contact wrongly labeled as 'me'. What should I do so that I can label the right person as 'me'? How do I change 'me'?

I'm using iOS8.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Within the Settings application, go to ‘Mail Contacts and Calendars’ and scroll down to the Contacts section.

   In later versions of iOS, there are three separate pages, one of which is ‘Contacts’.
2. Change the selection within My Info to the correct contact.

Comment: I did the changes as described - it moved the "me" but it didn't take effect at the top of the contact list until I powered the iphone off and then back on.

Comment: Just leave it for a day and it will work mine changed